# SSIS step to PGP file fails in agent

Tags: encryption, ssis, sftp, sql-agent

I have created a txt file from our source databases to be sent externally via SFTP, so needs to be encrypted.
I have 2 script tasks using C# in the SSIS package that encrypts and SFTP's; the first step uses Gpg4win to encrypt the file and the second step picks up the encrypted file and using WinSCP sends the file via SFTP to our external partner.
This package runs fine within Visual Studio, once deployed to the catalog and I schedule the job it succeeds although the file does not encrypt or SFTP. 
The Owner of the job in the agent has full permissions of the folder where the file is.
Has anyone else come across something similar to this?

Comment: Please format your question, it's hard to read.

Comment: *"to be sent externally via SFTP, **so needs to be** encrypted"* - I do not see any relation between SFTP and encryption, so what do you mean by the ***"so"***?

Comment: Also, start with one of the tasks only. Choose the encryption or SFTP and ask about it only. Those two might possibly have have two distinct problems.

Comment: The data is sensitive so that is the reason it needs to be encrypted. Also as both steps call a 3rd party software I would believe that the problem is the same for both steps. I don't believe there are two distinct problems.

Comment: Not matter what you think, you have to show us what your task are actually doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Owner of the job in the agent has full permissions of the folder where the file is.

The Owner of a SQL Job is not the account used to 'run' the job. You need to set the 'Run As' property. And to do that you need to set up a Sql Server Agent Proxy (and probably a Credential too).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy

Comment: Worked first time with a new proxy, thanks for the help.